# C# automated test exits without error before executing all logic

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, automated-tests

hope someone can help.

When I run the below code, the test passes, but when debugging I noticed that the code exits after doing the post, so at this line

```
var result = await client.PostAsync("endpoint/post", content);
```

I would like to go a get to read the response after I have posted. I get no error/exception whatsoever so I cannot understand why it is exiting at that point and not completing the rest of the code.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    [TestMethod}
    public async Task PostRequest()
    {
        var postContent = "{\"id\":\"a4e21b7e-2f26-4031-98b6-b8754ccffc14\"}";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://postendpointbaseurl");

            // serialize your json using newtonsoft json serializer then add it to the StringContent
            var content = new StringContent(postContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var result = await client.PostAsync("endpoint/post", content);
            string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + "endpoint/post");
            var getcontent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the test passing ? Sounds like an exception is thrown.

Comment: yes the test is passing and probably an exception is thrown but i can't see any errors in the output or debug window.

Comment: You can press `Ctrl + Alt + E` and ask Visual Studio to break when any exception is thrown. Or just surround the test in `try/catch` to see what's happening.

Comment: Thanks, looks like no exception is thrown, so not sure why it won't continue to the next line of code before exiting.

Comment: @RShome,I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer, which can help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for looking into it, but worked it out in the end.

My method was not returning anything
so I changed to

public async Task<string PostRequest()

instead of

public async Task PostRequest()

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a slash at the end of the base address, it should be

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://postendpointbaseurl/");
```

and

```
var result = await client.PostAsync("endpoint/post/", content);
```

If you leave out the slash, the last part is ignored.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I tried that and it still didn't work unfortunately.